# How to scale a rectangle at its position

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am drawing a rectangle and when i scale it , the rectangle starts to move towards the centre of the screen.

```
float vertices[] = {
         10.0f,  5.5f, 1.0f, 0.0 , 0.0,  // top right
         10.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0 , 0.0,  // bottom right
         5.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0 , 0.0,  // bottom left
         5.0f, 5.5f, 1.0f , 0.0 , 0.0  // top left 
    };

    unsigned int indices[] = {  // note that we start from 0!
        0, 1, 3,  // first Triangle
        1, 2, 3   // second Triangle
    };
```

the code from the drawing function.

```
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);      
    glm::mat4 view = camera1.GetViewMatrix();
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
   shader.setMat4("model", model);
   model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f));
   shader.setMat4("model", model);
   glBindVertexArray(VAO);
   glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
   glBindVertexArray(0);
```

the matrix multiplication in the vertex shader

```
gl_Position =   projection * view * model * vec4(aPos , 1.0 );
```

how can i scale my rectangle without it being moved toward the centre ?

I tried to first center the object and than applied transformation.

```
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(-7.75, 0.0, 0.0));
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f));
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(7.75, 0.0, 0.0));
        shader.setMat4("model", model);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seem to be the correct behavior.  For what you want then you need to center your object perfectly at the origin (0,0,0) first.  Your model transformation must be apply in this order, first center it at the origin, scale and rotation happen first around this origin then translate it.  Essentially these are the order of transformation steps you want to do to the object (object space, also know as the model transformations).

Comment: i have tried the way mentioned by you and updated the code but it still moves from its position.

Comment: You only centered the X-axis of your shape.  For it to behave the way you wanted, you want to center your object completely, so the center of your triangle have to be at 0,0,0.  So you need to translate -2.75 in the y and -0.5 in z.